# Menu links are unclickable in parent negative z-index container.

Tags: html, css

I need to design menus like the image. I have achieved it so far by border radius and negative layers but the fourth and the fifth menu items cannot be clicked. Need your suggestion. Here is the [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/NZwH2/)

Menu design to be achieved:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following properties to the classes. Since the "Third Menu" is at the top of all the menu(Layers) and "Second Menu" and "Fourth Menu" are on the same level. Similarly "First Menu" and "Fifth Menu" also have the same level of layers. Here i how i achieved it.

```
.menu div.three{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.menu div.four{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.menu div.five{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is the updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NZwH2/10/)